# XDebug configured and installed but not working

Tags: php, windows, installation, xdebug, opcache

I followed instructions how to install xdebug.
So, I created file with phpinfo() function, that returns me php info.
Then copied php info and used xdebug wizard: https://xdebug.org/wizard
That returns me:
[image]

I followed instructions, so I downloaded .dll file , moved it to location. Edited php.ini file as said but result is still Xdebug installed: no

[image]
[image]

Also I restarted apache server on my xamp control panel.

Comment: You need to check your web server log to perhaps find out why the file wasn't loaded.

Comment: The wizard also says that you need to put the Xdebug line *below* the line to load opcache, you put it above. This will cause issues. And why did you put the filename in "'s ? You're sure they're not in curly quotes?

Comment: @Derick I also added xdebug line bellow on every posible place, like at the end of the file, or like after last line where is opcache is mentioned, after [ocpcache] etc, but result is same.

In log file there's only this error about xdebug:
Failed loading C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.3-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what's the problem...
I downloaded non treat safe file, so i just downloaded tred safe file and replaced nts.
Just copied name of new (tread safe file) and paste it in php.ini file like:

zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.3-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll"

As you can see, the old wan was:
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.3-8.0-vs16-nts-x86_64.dll"

So, be careful wich one file you downloaded because names are very similar. :D
On image I higligted correct version:

[image]

Comment: The wizard linked to the exact right file to download though.